# Connections in graphql for pagination

Tags: pagination, graphql, connection

I am new to graphql and am trying to learn how connections work for pagination. I am following documentation here: https://graphql-ruby.org/pagination/using_connections.html. 
I am able to use `connection_type` to view say `User` in graphiql.

> 

```js
field :allUsers, Type::MyUsers.connection_type, null: false

      def allUsers
        Users.all
      end
```

I am not able to understand how to write code in `Make connection fields` and `Return collections` as per the documentation if I want to see the User-Post data. 
For Users-Post relation, I have nested the return type in `Type::MyUsers`, something like:

```js
class myUsers < GraphApi::BaseObject
      field :name, String, null: false
      field :created_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: true
      field :userPosts, Types::myPosts.connection_type, null: true
end
```

How do I get the data in posts so that when I see in graphiql the result should be something like:

```js
query {
  users {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage,
      endCursor
    }
    edges {
      node {[
        {name : "User1",
        userPosts {
          edges {
            nodes{ [
              {body: "post1"},
              {body: "post2"}
              ]
            }  
          }
        }},
        {name : "User2",
        userPosts {
          edges {
            nodes{ [
              {body: "post12"},
              {body: "post22"}
              ]
            }  
          }
        }}
        ]
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLN: The only piece missing was:

```js
class myUsers < GraphApi::BaseObject
      field :name, String, null: false
      field :created_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: true
      field :userPosts, Types::myPosts.connection_type, null: true
      
      def userPosts
        object.posts
      end
end
```

There was a typo in the resolver name and hence it did not work